# The Node Editor won't work for the object selected

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm still learning, but I'm trying to follow a tutorial to apply texture to a model.
I only want to apply the texture to one object in the scene, so I selected it, unwrapped it, and painted over it.
Now I selected it in the Edit Mode (I can't select it in the Object mode because all is locked together) and went into Node Editor, but the nodes are greyed out. 
Why?

[image]

Comment: did you assign the selected faces to your material? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Is *Use Nodes* enabled for your material?

Comment: Noob mistake! I'm new to Cycles... Hopefully this question can help newbies in the future? Make your comment an answer to let me select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure *Use Nodes* is enabled in the header of the node editor or in the properties editor:

[image]